# SharePoint 2010 topology to have only 3 WFEs and NO APP server?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

Unusual situation here. We have very high usage from workflows and site browsing on the 2 current WFEs but very little stress on the app server. We have a limitation of 3 servers so our thought was to convert the app server to an additional WFE. It would still run CA, majority of search, and additional services but would also provide a little bit of resources to take some load off of the 2 other WFEs.

I understand the steps needed to add an additional server to a farm but wanted to double check a couple things for just simply converting one.

To have the app pools and sites added to the newly converted server would we just start (Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application) and (Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service) or would we have to still run the configuration wizard?

Any other tips or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add those two roles, no need to run the config wizard again.  You technically still have an App server, it will just also be a web front end as well.  Make sure that you add the additional server to your load balancer.  If you have the option to reduce the load on the third server, you might consider doing that to make sure the server has resources for search and other service application needs.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to run the config wizard on that server as it is part of the farm. You should make sure following things.

- Update the Loadbalancer( to add this server for traffic)
- Update the IIS ( bindings, SSL certs[if any])
- Make sure the web.config is updated on this server, if you have any
- if you have any other custom settings on other WFE, please make sure they are present here.

Other than that, you will be fine as Central Admin is running on that server. Onside note, please get your extra box as i am worried may be you can mess up with search( extra load).